# Error Message: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]:
MySQL server has gone away in C:\wamp\www\amp10\hrd_consultant_ho_all_display.php on line 254

Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Error reading result set's header in C:\wamp\www\amp10\hrd_consultant_ho_all_display.php on line 254

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\amp10\hrd_consultant_ho_all_display.php on line 254
```

I got this errors above from my query and i dont know how to resolve it. below is my codes. any help is accepted for a newbie... thanks

```
SELECT * , (SELECT CASE WHEN audited = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END FROM activity_ref WHERE         
activity_ref.ref_no = activity_plan.ref_no ) AS test_audited
FROM 
activity_plan
inner join user on activity_plan.sales_officer=user.username
INNER JOIN activity_liquid ON activity_plan.aplan_no = activity_liquid.aplan_no
where activity_plan.date between '$date1' and '$date2' and user.branch='no' and     
user.position='Consultant' and activity_plan.validate_1st_status!='pending'  order by     
activity_plan.sales_officer asc,activity_plan.aplan_no asc
```

Comment: use explain to get query result with profile. you can trace where the query takes time.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your PHP script may take long time to execute, so you may need to increase max_execution_time value in php.ini,

`max_execution_time=600` this is for 10 min

Answer (score 0):

See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html

> The most common reason for the MySQL server has gone away error is
>   that the server timed out and closed the connection. In this case, you
>   normally get one of the following error codes (which one you get is
>   operating system-dependent).